# Laravel 5 deployment getting internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5, web-deployment

Laravel 5 deployment getting :

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request

My file structure:

```
|
|-pub                           -> from laravel folder public
|-my_apps
     |- my_first_app            -> all other files from laravel project
           |- app
           |- bootstrap
           |- config
           |- database
           |- resources
           |- storage
           |- ...
```

I have set storage folder permission to be:

user::rwx

group::rwx

other::rwx

This is my .htaccess file in directory `/pub`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /  <-------- I added this line

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also change path in `\pub\index.php`

```
<?php

//updated path
require __DIR__.'/../my_apps/my_first_app/bootstrap/autoload.php';

//updated path
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../my_apps/my_first_app/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

PHP on my local machine is PHP 5.6, it is PHP 5.5. I tried to add

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php
```

in .htaccess after `RewriteEngine On` line.

## update

The server runs PHP 5.5.0, so I downgraded my Laravel 5.1 to 5.0, and it works on homestead now.
And I'm following https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e#.50q2s8wer for deployment at this moment. **Downgrade actually failed** when I check version of laravel

Comment: Check laravel and apache logs for more information about nature of the error.

Comment: Check for the php version

Comment: php version 5.5.0 on the server and I used php 5.6 on homestead for developing

Comment: Downgrading to laravel 5 with the changes you made in the default codes is working correctly? What do you mean by: "_and it works on **homestead** now_."

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.1 requires PHP 5.5.9, per [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel).

Laravel 5.0 has no bound PHP version requirement, per [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel#v5.0.22), however anything less than PHP 5.5 is Not A Good Idea.

Since your server runs 5.5.0 (per comment), then I'm guessing you installed this outside of composer.  Downgrade your Laravel environment or upgrade your PHP environment. Upgrading PHP is A Good Idea.

Comment: I already downgraded my laravel to 5.0, still getting Internal Server Error. I don't have permission to upgrade PHP on server

Comment: Alright. "Internal Server Error" usually (but not exclusively) means Laravel emitted an uncaught exception (eg, bad configuration) or PHP encountered a Fatal Error (eg, syntax error).  Check your Apache, PHP, and Laravel logs and post the results as an update. Apache logs are often in `/var/log/httpd/` or `/var/log/apache`. PHP error logs are often in `/var/log/messages`, but `php -i | grep error` will tell more. Laravel logs are often in your application directory under `storage/logs`. [More here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors)

Answer (score 1):

"Internal Server Errors" maybe caused by many reason. Library is not installed, misconfiguration, version conflicted.

So please check the apache errors in `/var/log/apache` or `/var/log/httpd`, Laravel errors for more detail about the error. If you cannot see error, be sure that you turned on php display error in `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you could check the logs in /var/log/apache2 or /var/log/httpd for errors, it would be much helpful. But, since you said that your server is running PHP 5.5.0 and

> Downgrade actually failed when I check version of laravel

so, clearly the most probable reason is that your server is trying to run  laravel 5.1 with PHP 5.5.0 which is [not supported](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/#installation). The solution for you now is to create a fresh project with laravel 5.0 and then copy code files you have created from current project to the new project and update them accordingly so that they work with laravel 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was as simple as a case-sensitivity typo in one of my includes. I develop on a Windows machine, which doesn't care about case-sensitivity in file paths. After deploying to a Linux server however I got the infamous Internal Server error.

Checking laravels php_errors.log quickly made it clear what was wrong.